# Failed to load idd sample driver on windows 10 1809?

Tags: driver, indirect-display-driver

I build microsoft iddsampledriver, set _NT_TARGET_VERSION to 10.0.14393, UMDF version to 2.19 and IddCx version to 1.0
When install the driver on windows 10 1809, but failed to load with error CM_PROB_FAILED_ADD.

I try to windbg and confirm that DllMain is called with true returned, then terminates:

```
0:008> bu iddsampledriver!DllMain
0:008> bu iddsampledriver!DriverEntry
0:008> g
UMDF: User-mode debugger found - breaking in.
(1a98.aa4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WUDFPlatform.dll - 
KERNELBASE!DebugBreak+0x2:
00007ff8`389c2452 cc              int     3
0:006> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
iddsampledriver!DllMain:
00007ff8`1d324b00 4c89442418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],r8 ss:00000018`19d7f350=0000e9f0772e30d7
0:009> g
ModLoad: 00007ff8`18720000 00007ff8`1890d000   C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll
Breakpoint 0 hit
iddsampledriver!DllMain:
00007ff8`1d324b00 4c89442418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],r8 ss:00000018`19cff700=0000e9f077363527
0:008> g
Wudfx2000: FxDriverEntrydUm Enter PDRIVER_OBJECT_UM 0x000001C82F4C4540
ModLoad: 00007ff8`10e60000 00007ff8`10efc000   C:\Windows\System32\WUDFx02000.dll
Wudfx2000: FxDriverEntryUm: PDRIVER_OBJECT_UM 0x000001C82F4C4540 Successfully bound to version library
FxStubBindClasses: VersionBindClass WDF_CLASS_BIND_INFO 0x00007FF81D32F1F0, class IddCx, returned status 0x80070002
Breakpoint 0 hit
iddsampledriver!DllMain:
00007ff8`1d324b00 4c89442418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],r8 ss:00000018`19bfeca0=0000000000000000
0:006> g
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14:
00007ff8`3c820d74 c3              ret
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

After DllMain is called, FxStubBindClasses return 0x80070002 when bind class IddCx then terminates. It's confirmed that IddCx version is supported by win10 1809 of which os internal version is 17763. But why WDF failed to bind classes?